# routing NoSQL and SQL backed fields in a single django Model

Tags: sql, django, django-models, nosql

Is it possible to route fields in a single Model to different databases NoSQL and SQL? If not are there design that emulate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that it is possible to use several databases for the individual fields of a single Model.

Django's multiple database documentation is available here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/